# react native expo dev client tunnel generates invalid url

Tags: react-native, expo, ngrok, eas, expo-dev-client

i have an app built with expo and i have custom dev client. I'm using `npx expo start --dev-client --tunnel` command to run app. I need tunnel option to be able to connect to dev client via public url, but it seems like it generates invalid url, because i'm getting following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Invalid input to toASCIl:
4Igmz_k-omendilly-8081.exp.direct
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIr6i.jpg)

i tried running app in local and it's working just fine, but when i'm running exactly the same command with `--tunnel` flag, it's throwing an error

Comment: Hi can you please try to run without --tunnel and also can you please show your package. json, app.json file ?